# How to get certain values from string

Tags: python, string

I am using proxyscrape to get free proxys but the current ouput is:

`Proxy(host='181.214.23.210', port='3129', code='us', country='united states', anonymous=True, type='https', source='us-proxy')`

How can I slice up this string so I end up with an output which just is IP:PORT?

This is how my current code looks:

```
from proxyscrape import create_collector

collector = create_collector('my-collector', 'http')

# Retrieve only 'us' proxies
proxygrab = collector.get_proxy({'code': 'us'})

print (proxygrab)
```

Any help would be very appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`proxygrab` is not a string but an object. You could just print elements:

```
print(proxygrab.host)
print(proxygrab.port)
```

and to combine them:

```
print("{}:{}".format(proxygrab.host, proxygrab.port))
```

would give:

```
181.214.23.210:3129
```

Answer (score 3):

This returns a `collections.namedtuple`, so you can just do:

```
from proxyscrape import create_collector

collector = create_collector('my-collector', 'http')

# Retrieve only 'us' proxies
proxygrab = collector.get_proxy({'code': 'us'})

print(f"{proxygrab.host}:{proxygrab.port}")
```

Gives:

```
181.214.23.124:3129
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from proxyscrape import create_collector

collector = create_collector('my-collector', 'http')

# Retrieve only 'us' proxies
proxygrab = collector.get_proxy({'code': 'us'})


# This print only the first element 181.214.23.210
print(proxygrab[0])

# This print only the first element 3129
print(proxygrab[1])

#so on for others
```

if you want only IP:PORT

```
# This print IP:PORT
print(proxygrab[0] + ":" + proxygrab[1])
```

if you want more then one IP:PORT (in this case is 10 ip:port)

```
collector = create_collector('my-collector', 'http')

# Change the second range number for print more or less ip:port
for index in range(1,10):

    proxygrab = collector.get_proxy({'code': 'us'})
    print(proxygrab[0] + ":" + proxygrab[1])
```